# Machine Learning Model To predict game outcome During the game

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I'm trying to build a ML model to predict sports (tennis, soccer, basketball, football).

I would like to have two models : model A to do the pre-game prediction (given historical matches data, injury data, weather, places, player ages, etc) to predict a game before the game starts.

Second model B to predict the game during the game (for tennis, given previous states to predict the next round; for soccer given previous 10 minutes to predict the next minutes or final game outcome).

However, I'm quite stuck on the second model;

I don't know where to start; where do I get the during-game data? How should my Model B looks like; what algorithm would be good? what kind of in-game feature should I consider ? etc

any suggestions (a link with relevant papers would be awesome.)

Answer (score 0):

for second model, I think that you need a real-time streaming model with spark perhaps, the features collected for second model should vary from first one ( or at least some features), there are some options in the market for  prediction using incremental data realtime data. what algorithm to use is quite hard to say at this stage, you could try the one used in first model, however, due to variation of your data, the result may not be optimal as you prefer. In that case, just have to keep trying with different algorithms.